# Sorting a string alphabetically by line in Clojure(Script)

Tags: string, clojure, clojurescript

Suppose `S` is a string defined as follows:

```
;; S
B
C
A
```

Is there some clojure operation `sort-alphabetically` (that also works in clojurescript) such that `(sort-alphabetically S)` generates the following string?

```
;; (sort-alphabetically S) =>
A
B
C
```

Comment: Please share the `def` statement you are using to create your strings.

Answer (score 2):

The following code snippet will do what you want:

```
(require '[clojure.string :as str])

(def s "C\nB\nA")

(->> s
  (str/split-lines) ; split your string into sequence of lines
  (sort) ; sort the sequence using natural order (for strings it will be alphabetical order)
  (str/join "\n")) ; join elements of the sorted sequence using \n producing a multiline string

;; => "A\nB\nC"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
(def foo "a\ne\nc")
(:use clojure.string)
(sort (clojure.string/split foo #"\n"))
;; ("a" "c" "e")
```

In general you should try to provide a definition of the data that is executable or at least enclosed in parens to make it clear exactly what the data looks like, per the advice of @jmargolisvt